# Customize system tray icons in KDE

Tags: 15.10, kde, system-tray, qsystemtrayicon

Is there anyway to use customized icons for notification center? Some programs like Skype has very different icons.

Maybe using another notification center manager can be solution, but I didn't find any.

I am using Kubuntu 15.10  with plasma version 5.4.2